How to setup PropertyChanging.Fody without errors?
I've been using PropertyChanged.Fody for years.
Now I want to also intercept PropertyChanging (to disallow certain property changes). So I installed PropertyChanging.Fody, but it caused errors. So I uninstalled and deleted anything related to Fody in my projects, and reinstalled only PropertyChanging.Fody. Still I get an error.
I'm not even using or implementing anything Fody in my project currently. I just installed and already I can't compile. Here is the error I get:

1>MSBUILD : warning FodyPackageReference: Fody: The package reference
for PropertyChanging.Fody does not contain PrivateAssets='All'
1>MSBUILD : error : Fody: An unhandled exception occurred: 1>MSBUILD :
error : Exception: 1>MSBUILD : error : Failed to execute weaver
C:\Users\y2.nuget\packages\propertychanging.fody\1.30.3\build..\weaver\PropertyChanging.Fody.dll
1>MSBUILD : error : Type: 1>MSBUILD : error : System.Exception
1>MSBUILD : error : StackTrace: 1>MSBUILD : error :    at
InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in
C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 222 1>MSBUILD :
error :    at InnerWeaver.Execute() in
C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 113 1>MSBUILD :
error : Source: 1>MSBUILD : error : FodyIsolated 1>MSBUILD : error :
TargetSite: 1>MSBUILD : error : Void ExecuteWeavers() 1>MSBUILD :
error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
1>MSBUILD : error : Type: 1>MSBUILD : error :
System.NullReferenceException 1>MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
1>MSBUILD : error :    at
ModuleWeaver.HasPropertyChangingEvent(TypeDefinition typeDefinition)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at
ModuleWeaver.HierarchyImplementsINotify(TypeReference typeReference)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at
ModuleWeaver.HierarchyImplementsINotify(TypeReference typeReference)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at ModuleWeaver.PopulateINotifyNodes(List`1
typeNodes) 1>MSBUILD : error :    at ModuleWeaver.BuildTypeNodes()
1>MSBUILD : error :    at ModuleWeaver.Execute() 1>MSBUILD : error :
at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in
C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 186 1>MSBUILD :
error : Source: 1>MSBUILD : error : PropertyChanging.Fody 1>MSBUILD :
error : TargetSite: 1>MSBUILD : error : Boolean
HasPropertyChangingEvent(Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition) 1>MSBUILD : error
: 1>Done building project "General.vbproj" -- FAILED.

I have 2 Projects. a vase project called "General". and another Project called MyPhone which references General. I installed to both projects. and both give the same error.
The weavers were created in both projects and seem okay.
Deleting bin/obj and cleaning solution multiple times makes no difference.
What can the issue be?
In the end of course I need both. Also PropertyChanging and aslo PropertyChanged.
I'd appreciate any help
Thanks in Advance
